# update crossdomain.xml on stackauth.com and api endpoints to work with current Flash

Tags: bug, status-completed, silverlight, flash

I am implementing a javascript client that uses the Flash based XHR replacement [Flensed](http://flxhr.flensed.com) in the interest of providing more robust api communication than that provided by JSONP.

Apparently the current flash version does not like the current crossdomain.xml.

The only difference I can see between a policy file that works with Flensed, thus Flash 10, is the inclusion of the xml directive and doc-type. In other words, a semantically correct crossdomain xml file.

Can we deploy the proposed version of crossdomain.xml on stackauth and all api endpoints?

**Current:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <cross-domain-policy>
      <allow-access-from domain="*" />  
      <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>  
    </cross-domain-policy>
```

**Proposed:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
      <allow-access-from domain="*" />  
      <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>  
    </cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Given the official [Cross-domain policy file specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) (and the fact that it isn't working correctly currently) I'd qualify this as a bug actually (have retagged accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are rolling out, and should be on all API and StackAuth instances soon-ish.

Comment: http://stackauth.com/crossdomain.xml & http://stackauth.com/1.0/crossdomain.xml  are either lagging update or were missed. these are actually the most critical of the bunch.