# Support Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, javascript

Currently, the only way to call the API from javascript is to use JSONP, but this can be cumbersome and has security issues. If the following header was included in all API responses, the API could be called through javascript [in most browsers](http://caniuse.com/cors):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

See [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) for more information. Similar features have already [been enabled](https://stackapps.com/questions/1659/update-crossdomain-xml-on-stackauth-com-and-api-endpoints-to-work-with-current-fl) in [Flash](http://api.stackoverflow.com/crossdomain.xml) and [Silverlight](http://api.stackoverflow.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml), and doing the same for javascript would be useful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... which browsers currently support this?

Comment: @George Edison: http://caniuse.com/cors

Comment: Cool. I would love to see this implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

API V2 did this, we send down:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

With every response.