# The API has stopped allowing CORS requests

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

I just noticed that a script I have that [makes CORS requests](https://stackapps.com/questions/2964/api-endpoints-do-not-set-access-control-allow-origin-so-cors-requests-fail) to the API stopped working on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), claiming that the domain isn't allowed by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, which is true since the header seems to have disappeared from the response. Could this please be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.